# Adding Infinite Scroll functionality to my JSON Flickr feed script?

Tags: jquery, json, scroll, flickr, infinite

I'm creating a photoblog to display my 365 project photos. This is what I've currently got. It returns my whole photostream in one go...

```
    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ea494d6b294a94aed2a1f5a04530e387&user_id=57288432@N00&extras=description,date_taken&jsoncallback=?',

function(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, rPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret;
        var thumbPhotoURL = basePhotoURL + '.jpg';
        var mediumPhotoURL = basePhotoURL + '_b.jpg';

        var photoStringBuild = '<article style="background-image:url(' + thumbPhotoURL + ')"> <span class="info"><h1><a href="' + mediumPhotoURL + '" title="' + rPhoto.title + '">' + rPhoto.title + '</a></h1><h2>' + rPhoto.datetaken + '</h2><p>' + rPhoto.description._content + '</p></span> </article>';

            photoStringBuild : photoStringBuild ;

        $(photoString).appendTo("#flickr");
    });
});
```

This works. See here (http://hey.ac). What I'd like to do is now add infinite scroll functionality so that photos are loaded incrementally as the browser is scrolled down.

I've downloaded Infinite Scroll (https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) which looks excellent. This is as far as my jQuery hacking ability takes me though. I've gone through the readme and the JSON section provides the following code which looks like it may be close to what I should be using...

```
  $('#flickr').infinitescroll({
  // other options
  dataType: 'json',
  appendCallback: false
}, function(json, opts) {
  // Get current page
  var page = opts.state.currPage; 
  // Do something with JSON data, create DOM elements, etc ..
});
```

I'd like some pointers to help figure this out. Cheers, Ali

Comment: Just curious .. what is this line good for: `var photoString = (i < 500) ? photoStringBuild : photoStringBuild` ?

Comment: Have you also checked out the lazyload plugin? I think its easier to implement to your example. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: hi @sofl, I'm not a strong programmer :) I have now removed that line and it still works fine, thanks.

Comment: Lazyload looks interesting. The main difference with my version is that mine doesn't actually contain <img> elements. All the thumbnails are CSS backgrounds on the <article> elements. I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Whether I use Lazyload or Infinite Scroll or any other solution my jquery/js experience isn't good enough to merge it with my existing code...

Comment: Basically it works with image tags, thats correct. I made you a little example for your needs http://jsfiddle.net/dpVSq/3/ . I noticed that this example is a bit slow so maybe the infinite plugin is still the better choice here.

Comment: That's beautiful. I owe you a beer @sofl